# How can I stop a sycamore tree from sprouting new growth?

Tags: trees

How can I stop a pollarded sycamore from sprouting new growth?

Comment: To directly answer your question, kill it. Otherwise, see Bamboo's answer, and keep the shears handy to cut early and often if you don't want to remove/kill it.

Answer (score 7):

On the assumption you mean new growth which is not at the top of the cut parts, but arising either on the trunk or from below ground, you can't I'm afraid. If you pollard trees, many of them produce epicormic shoots as well as suckers off the roots as a direct response to the cutting back. Some trees are more prone to this than others, but epicormic shoots in particular are suppressed by the presence of topgrowth - if the topgrowth or canopy endures damage, dieback or pollarding/coppicing, the epicormic buds are activated, and new shoots arise.